# tModLoader issues with compiling

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

So I am making my own Terraria Mod but I have one problem which is that when I use one the the items from my mod in a crating recipe for something else in my mod it gives me an error.

This is the item that uses something from my mod:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Terraria;
using Terraria.Graphics.Effects;
using Terraria.Graphics.Shaders;
using Terraria.ID;
using Terraria.ModLoader;

namespace TestMod.Items.Weapons     //Where it is located
{
    public class BladeOfTheElements : ModItem
    {
        public override void SetDefaults()
        {
            item.name = "Blade Of The Elements";      //Sword name
            item.damage = 26;       //Sword damage - Damage is x2.5 - 43 here = 109 in game
            item.crit = -46;     //Crit chance of the weapon
            item.melee = true;      //Is it a melee item?
            item.width = 74;        //Sword width
            item.height = 74;      //Sword height
            item.toolTip = "A blade containing the power of; Fire, Ice and Forest";      //Item Description
            item.useTime = 23;       //How fast is the item? How fast does it swing or shoot?
            item.useAnimation = 23;
            item.useStyle = 1;          //How is the item used? 1 is sword
            item.knockBack = 4;     //The knockback of the item
            item.value = 100000;     //How much does it sell for? 100 = 1 Silver
            item.rare = 5;
            item.useSound = 1;      //What sound type? 1 is sword
            item.autoReuse = true;      //If it's a sword can it autoswing?
            item.useTurn = true;
            item.shoot = mod.ProjectileType("BladeOfTheElementsProj");
            item.shootSpeed = 6f;       //Speed of the projectile
        }
        public override void AddRecipes()       //How do you craft the item?
        {
            ModRecipe recipe = new ModRecipe(mod);
            recipe.AddIngredient(ItemID.BladeOfTheForest, 1);      //What do you need to craft the item? (Use 1 dirt block for testing)
            recipe.AddIngredient(ItemID.BladeOfIce, 1);
            recipe.AddIngredient(ItemID.BladeOfTheDemons, 1);
            recipe.AddTile(TileID.Anvils);        //Where is it made? Work bench, anvil, water? etc (Use worck bench for testing)
            recipe.SetResult(this);
            recipe.AddRecipe();
        }
    }
}
```

All the blades in the crafting recipe at the bottom are from my mod but I get this error when I try and compile my mod:

An error occured while compiling a mod.

```
c:/Users/Nicolas/Documents/My Games/Terraria/ModLoader/Mod Sources/TestMod/Items/Weapons/BladeOfTheElements.cs(37,41) : error CS0117: 'Terraria.ID.ItemID' does not contain a definition for 'BladeOfTheForest'
```

I'd just like to point out that when I used dirt blocks for the recipe (To test the weapon) I could compile the mod just fine.

Comment: This looks like a C# question, not a Visual C++ question. You might want to add a [c#] tag so the right people look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Because those weps the BladeOfTheForest the BladeOfIce and the BladeOfTheDemons are not vanilla items - I guess you made them - they aren't in the main game, so they aren't `ItemID.etc`. Use just `BladeOfTheForest`, `BladeOfIce` and `BladeOfTheDemons` instead of those.

```
recipe.AddIngredient("BladeOfTheForest", 1);
recipe.AddIngredient("BladeOfIce", 1);
recipe.AddIngredient("BladeOfTheDemons", 1);
```